# Aggregating over multiple categories with sub results

Tags: python, python-3.x, aggregate

This seems like a simple enough problem, but I just couldn’t find anything on it.
I have dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,3,1,3,1,5,1,5],
                   'cat1':['A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B'],
                  'cat2':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})

    cat1 cat2 x
0   A    A    1
1   A    A    3
2   B    A    1
3   B    A    3
4   A    B    1
5   A    B    5
6   B    B    1
7   B    B    5
```

Where cat1 and cat 2 are some categories, and I want aggregate x over them using some aggregate function (sum, weighted average or something defined). The obvious solution, like

```
res = df.groupby(['cat1','cat2']).sum()
```

results in

```
           x
cat1 cat2   
A    A     4
     B     6
B    A     4
     B     6
```

But what I want is this:

```
    cat1    cat2    x
0   A       A       4
1   A       B       6
2   A       Any     10
3   B       A       4
4   B       B       6
5   B       Any     10
6   Any     A       8
7   Any     B       12
8   Any     Any     20
```

One way to go is with something like this:

```
res2 = df.groupby(['cat1','cat2']).sum().reset_index()
res1a = df.groupby(['cat1']).sum().reset_index()
res1b = df.groupby(['cat2']).sum().reset_index()
res1a['cat2'] = 'any'
res1b['cat1'] = 'any'
res = res1a.append(res1b).append(res2).set_index(['cat1','cat2'])
```

But since my actual task involves about 10 categories, creating separate groupbys for various category subsets and appending it all together is not convenient. I hope there is a better way to go

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape, add new column and new row `Any` with `sum` and last reshape back by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
#add `['x']` for Series output
res = df.groupby(['cat1','cat2'])['x'].sum()
print (res)
cat1  cat2
A     A       4
      B       6
B     A       4
      B       6
Name: x, dtype: int64

a = res.unstack()
a['Any'] = a.sum(axis=1)
a.loc['Any'] = a.sum()
print (a)
cat2  A   B  Any
cat1            
A     4   6   10
B     4   6   10
Any   8  12   20

df1 = a.stack()
print (df1)
cat1  cat2
A     A        4
      B        6
      Any     10
B     A        4
      B        6
      Any     10
Any   A        8
      B       12
      Any     20
dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

```
res2 = df.groupby(['cat1','cat2']).sum()
res1a = df.groupby(['cat1']).sum()
res1b = df.groupby(['cat2']).sum()
res1a = res1a.set_index(pd.Series(['any'] * len(res1a), name='cat2'), append=True)
res1b=res1b.set_index(pd.Series(['any'] * len(res1b), name='cat1'), append=True).swaplevel()
res1ab=pd.DataFrame(res1a.sum().values, 
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['any'],['any']]),
                   columns=['x'])

res2 = pd.concat([res2, res1a, res1b, res1ab])
print (res2)
            x
cat1 cat2    
A    A      4
     B      6
B    A      4
     B      6
A    any   10
B    any   10
any  A      8
     B     12
     any   20
```

Comment: The problem here is that my aggregate function isn’t always 'sum', and if you use average, or something more complicated, this method becomes inapplicable

Comment: I do like it for sums, though

Comment: Defining function this way doesn’t solve the problem – you can’t average over averages. Let’s say you had x values [1,3,1,3,1,3] for “A A” categories, which averages to 2, and [7,9] for “A B” categories (with average of 8). Averaging over the entire cat1 = “A” (that’s “A all”) gives (1+3+1+3+1+3+7+9)/8 = 3.5. (that’s the correct result). Averaging columns after groupby result is unstack yields (2+8)/2=5

Comment: I understand. But are you sure universal solution for all types of aggregation? I think it is possible, but need many `if, else, elif` statements for exceptions like mean. And if use some custom function, exceptions is more. In my opinion need custom functions for each aggregation, not one universalm spagetti code solution. What do you think?

Comment: The approach I once implemented in R went as follows. Say there are n categories, and we an array of categories column names catnames = [cat1, cat2, …, catn]. From this array, bunch of arrays are created containing all possible choices, like [ca1, cat2], [cat1, cat3] etc., so there are n one-column arrays, nC2 (n choose 2) 2 cols, then I  iterated over all those arrays. First, aggregates were computed for columns in the array, then columns not included in the array were added with values (“any”). Finally, all sub-categorical results were appended together. It worked ok, but seemed so bulky.

Comment: Hmmm, and it working for many aggreagate custom functions nice?

Comment: Main problem is in pandas making this subgroups is not implemented, so need this kind of solutions - some way create subcategories and then concat to original or  `stack` + `unstack` solution.

Comment: Also for concat solution is problem automatically sorted categories in Multiindex, so I prefer `stack`+`unstack`.

Comment: I’ve edited my question to illustrate my approach. It works for any aggregating function, since you don’t aggregate anything twice. You are right in that I should drop ‘pandas’ from tags

Comment: I try improve your solution, please check it.

Comment: It's faster by about 8%